# how to update data in php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Let's say I want to update a message row without deleting the previous message. For example: row message has the current value "hello", now I want to add "hi" without replacing the word "hello". So the result should be "hello hi".

I've tried the code below but it won't work:

```
$text="hi";

$sql = "UPDATE class SET message= message+'$text' WHERE id=2";
```

or

```
$sql = "UPDATE class SET message= 'message'.'$text' WHERE id=2";
```

sorry, im not really good at english. thanks for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do use the mysql's `concat()` function to append data to a field:

```
$sql = "update class set message = concat(ifnull(message,"")," ".'$text') where id=2";
```

You may also want to consider a space before appending the new content!

Comment: Quoting is missing around the variable `$text`.

Comment: how about adding a space?, since this code will result into hellohi

Comment: Use `concat_ws` in that case.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you should first of all you should really learn about [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) (and how to prevent it, including [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)).

You can do this in SQL using the [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

```
$sql = "UPDATE class SET message = CONCAT(message, '$text') WHERE id=2";
```

Comment: Using the first query will set the field `message` to `'messagehi'` instead of `'hello hi'` as the OP needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try CONCAT instead, in your mysql query.

```
$text = "hi";
$myQuery = "UPDATE class SET message= CONCAT(message,'".$text."') WHERE id=2";
```

You should use the CONCAT function which is used to concatenate strings.
Here since you are using the content of a php variable, it is good to escape the php variable from mysql query like `'".$text."'`;

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) Function of MySql:

```
$sql = "UPDATE class SET message=CONCAT(message, '".$text."') WHERE id=2";
```

should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$sql = "UPDATE class SET message=CONCAT(message, '$text') WHERE id='2'";
```

However, be aware that this is vulnerable to SQL Injections